# BILLING permission error in Console though it is not in manifest

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

History:
First we implemented In App Purchase of android and also uploaded that apk to alpha channel for testing. But later we remove that implementation. But when we tried to upload the apk in play store for production, we get the following message as warning:

"You uploaded an APK that does not have BILLING permission, or has a BILLING permission that is limited to specific sdk versions. BILLING permission is required for selling in-app products."

In manifest the following was already removed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Also in gradle file there was nothing for billing.

We also tried with the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" tools:node="remove" />
```

Also the products(sku) removed from google play developer console. 
But still the the warning is showing when upload apk for production.

We also added google pay with braintree, but the codes needed for google pay is also removed from manifest and gradle but commented out in java files. Are we missing something else?

Thanks in advance for anyone's help.....

Comment: I'd contact Google Play support via the Play console to answer this.

Comment: I already have contacted them 3 days ago, they said they have redirected my appeal to policy team. From the policy team an email has been sent to have patience and they will contact after more findings. 2 days have gone so far but no other email till now. Any kind of help is appreciated. So eagerly looking forward for your answer. Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

This is the BILLING permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Comment: Oh sorry for my mistake. I copied the the wrong one from another question. Correcting the question. But the problem is those are not in manifest. We have removed that implementation, but warning still showing.....